# Image Not Found 404 But Image Path Correctly in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I copy project laravel to new hosting and new domain, its working fine. But the problem is when i upload new image, that image successfully upload to file storage/app/public/upload/folder, but that image not showing on page. See below image

[image: not found 404 on page]

[image: path image correct]

Answer (score 1):

You need to run: `php artisan storage:link`
to link storage to public folder